# select_collection no Ruby on rails

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Se eu quero retornar as opções de *Ativo* e *Inativo* para que eu selecione, eu utilizo o seguinte codigo na view, então ele retorna os 2 status:

```
<%= select(:student, :status, Situation.all.collect { |c| [ c.descricao, c.id ] }) %>
```

mas eu preciso retornar não os 2 status, mas somente *Ativo* ou *Inativo*, dependendo de como está no banco, como eu poderia fazer ?

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara. Tem como exemplificar mais claramente o que está acontecendo e como você deseja que fique. Utilizando exemplos fica mais claro.

Comment: Ah você é o cara que e **não marca as respostas como certas** reveja suas perguntas anteriores cara. Marcar essas respostas como aceita ajuda quem respondeu e quem está buscando a solução como você.

Comment: ah tá..desculpe ..vou rever minhas perguntas...

Comment: Edite sua resposta para que possamos ajudar aqui também!

Comment: COnsegui resolver, vou postar abaixo a solução

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma...

**Na minha view**

```
<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= student['nome'] %></td>
    <td><%= student['matricula'] %></td>
    <td><%= student['sala'] %></td>
    <td><%= student['status']%></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student['id']) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', student_path(student['id']), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
```

---

**Na minha Model**

```
def ajustaDadosAluno
    queryRoom = "select s.id AS id,s.name AS nome, s.registration AS matricula, 
    r.description AS sala, si.descricao AS status FROM students s
    INNER JOIN rooms r ON r.id = s.room_id
    INNER JOIN situations si ON s.room_id = si.id"
    retorno= ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(queryRoom)
end
```

---

**Na minha controller**

```
def index
   #@students = Student.all
  #render :json => @students
  student = Student.new
  @students = student.ajustaDadosAluno
end
```

Comment: Você está usando esse SQL por necessidade ou porque não conseguiu reproduzi-lo utilizando a ORM do Rails?

Creio que você possa transformar esse método em um scope.

Comment: opa...Obg pelo comentário, então, eu não consegui reduzir para ORM, me perco nos joins, como seria transformar num scope ?

Answer (score 2):

Criar um scope no model:

```
class Situation < Application Record
    #suas validações e parametros

    scope :active, -> { where(status: 'active' }
    scope :inactive -> { where(status: 'inactive' }
end
```

Então você pode chamar na sua view:

```
#pega somente os ativos
<%= select(:student, :status, Situation.active.collect { |c| [ c.descricao, c.id ] }) %>

#pegar somente os inativos
<%= select(:student, :status, Situation.inactive.collect { |c| [ c.descricao, c.id ] }) %>
```